# filling a NaN column by another column content in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column having lots of NaN values. I need to updates these values by another column values when NaN is in the column.

```
    One    Two
0    10    21

1    11    NaN

2    12    25
```

I want a result like this

```
    One    Two

0    10    21

1    11    **11**

2    12    25
```

Please help me for the synthaxe of slicing in the column two and have Nafill detection to copy the value from column One.

This is the code to create the 1rst matrix :

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'One' : [10, 11, 12], 'Two' : [21, np.NAN, 25]})
```

Comment: Thank, very much for everybody to gave me 3 methods to do the change in the best way. Wonderful.

Comment: Hi everybody, by the time waiting for an answer I did this code, maybe it can help somebody : `df['Two'].where(df['Two'].notnull(), df['One'])` .This code is robust in front of NaN imported from csv or Excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) using that column:

```
In [4]: df['Two'].fillna(df['One'])
Out[4]:
0    21
1    11
2    25
Name: Two, dtype: float64
```

So to actually change the column: `df['Two'] = df['Two'].fillna(df['One'])`

Comment: thank you, this answer is working fine for my more complexe tab.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['TWO'].mask(df['TWO'].isnull(), df['ONE'], in_place=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be more precise I made some change in the proposal : `df['Two'].mask(df['Two'].isnull(), df['One'], inplace=True)`